# What exactly does the XNA redistributable installer do?

Tags: xna

I was wondering why I cannot just put all XNA dlls in the same directory as the game.exe, but I need to install that XNA redistributable?

if i try to run it i get an "assembly not found" error
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/shhcw6y9(v=vs.80).aspx
even though that assembly (dll) is there in the same directory.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well installers often do many other things than just copying files. For example XNA redist tries to install/update DirectX on a user computer to required version. I guess it can also write some required information to registry.

However, even if you can just copy XNA files with your game, that, most certainly, will violate license terms.

Comment: Yes you can only redistribute the redistributable not the separate XNA dlls that will violate the license.

Comment: thanks for the info about the license. actually i am still interested as to why a game doesnt run without the redistributable, though all DLLs are in the same directory as the exe.

Comment: @clamp see: "required information to registry" in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

When you have a redistributable, it usually is for not sending the end user the complete engine you used, as the end user only need some specific files. For XNA is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can examine the contents of any MSI installation package using tools like [less msiérables](https://blogs.pingpoet.com/overflow/archive/2005/06/02/2449.html) or [MSI Viewer](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/msi-viewer/9MZTR9QS01GN?hl=en-us&gl=us).

It's also possible to query via a script and the MSI API but it's non-trivial ([Docs](https://docs.revenera.com/installshield26helplib/LangRef/LangrefMsiApis.htm)).

Just be aware that *being able to see the contents doesn't give you any additional rights not already granted by the license*.